# HttpClient Response : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to understand why when I call an external API, I have different responses if I call from my local API or from a direct call from Visual Code with "Rest Client" extension.

I've got a error 400 in the 2 cases but with the direct call, I have the request's field which causes an issue

> { "identifier": "123456", "message": "Invalid sender code" }

and from my local API, I obtain:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I'm on Symfony 5.4.20

Thanks for your help

My controller

```
try{
   $response = $testHttpClient->authenticate();
   $bodyData = $request->attributes->get('bodyDataAuthenticate');
   $data = $response->toArray();
  
   //Test Token présent
   if(!isset($data['authenticationTicket'])){
     $message = 'Token Authorization non transmis';
     return new Response(json_encode(['wsel_log_id' => $wsel_log_id, 'response' => $data, 'error' => $message], $jsonFlags));
   }
   $token = $data['authenticationTicket'];
            
   //Récupération des données 
   $data = $savDb->getInfosDossier($params);
   //test récupération des données
   if(count($data) == 0){
      $message = 'Aucune donnée trouvée';
      return new Response(json_encode(['wsel_log_id' => $wsel_log_id, 'response' => $data, 'error' => $message], $jsonFlags));
   }
            
   //Carrier determination
   $response2 = $testHttpClient->carrierDetermination($params,$data[0],$token);
   $bodyData = $request->attributes->get('bodyDataCarrierDetermination');
   $data = $response->toArray();
                            
   return new Response('ok');
} catch (Exception $e) {
   $message = ($e instanceof ClientException) ? $e->getResponse()->getContent(false) : $e->getMessage();
   return new Response(json_encode(['wsel_log_id' => $wsel_log_id, 'request' => $bodyData, 'error' => $message], $jsonFlags));
}
```

My httpclient

```
public function carrierDetermination($params,$infosDossier,$token)
  {

    $data = 
    [
      .
      .
      .
    ];

    array_walk_recursive($data, function (&$item) { $item = strval($item); });

    $response = $this->client->request(
      "POST",
      "/external_api_url/carrierDeterminations",
      [
        'body' => json_encode($data),
        'headers' => [
          'Accept' => "*/*",
          'Content-Type' => "application/json",
          'Autorization' => "Bearer ".$token
        ],
        'timeout' => 100, //default : 0 => 30 seconds

      ]
    );
 
    $this->request->getCurrentRequest()->attributes->add(['bodyDataCarrierDetermination' => $data]);
    return $response;
```

The call "authenticate" works fine but the "carrierDetermination" throws an exception at $data = $response->toArray();

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

If I paste what I send in my direct call I obtain:

> { "identifier": "123456", "message": "Invalid sender code" }

I check in ->getHeaders or ->getInfo() but I don't find message from direct call

Comment: what is bodyDataAuthenticate? I  don't see that being set by the client

Comment: It's the body send in the call, just for log